# Can't run Apache Beam on separate Flink cluster. Official instructions don't work

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam

LE: I want to do this on macOS.

I am trying to run Apache Beam on a separate Flink cluster, as described here: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/flink/#executing-a-beam-pipeline-on-a-flink-cluster

> (1) Start a Flink cluster which exposes the Rest interface
> (e.g. localhost:8081 by default).

Flink 1.13.1 starts successfully on localhost:8081.

> (2) Start JobService with Flink Rest endpoint: `docker run --net=host apache/beam_flink1.10_job_server:latest --flink-master=localhost:8081`.

I am running this instead, which again starts successfully:

```
docker run --net=host apache/beam_flink1.13_job_server:latest --flink-master=localhost:8081
```

(3) Submit the pipeline as above.

I'm running the WordCount pipeline as:

```
python -m apache_beam.examples.wordcount --input /Users/stefan/datastore/input.txt
 --output /Users/stefan/datastore/output.txt
 --runner=PortableRunner --job_endpoint=localhost:8099
```

After 1 minute the pipeline crashes with a `grpc.FutureTimeoutError`. This is the full output:

```
WARNING:root:Make sure that locally built Python SDK docker image has Python 3.8 interpreter.
INFO:root:Default Python SDK image for environment is apache/beam_python3.8_sdk:2.31.0
INFO:root:No image given, using default Python SDK image
WARNING:root:Make sure that locally built Python SDK docker image has Python 3.8 interpreter.
INFO:root:Default Python SDK image for environment is apache/beam_python3.8_sdk:2.31.0
INFO:root:Python SDK container image set to "apache/beam_python3.8_sdk:2.31.0" for Docker environment
INFO:apache_beam.runners.portability.fn_api_runner.translations:==================== <function pack_combiners at 0x137d441f0> ====================
INFO:apache_beam.runners.portability.fn_api_runner.translations:==================== <function lift_combiners at 0x137d44280> ====================
INFO:apache_beam.runners.portability.fn_api_runner.translations:==================== <function sort_stages at 0x137d449d0> ====================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/stefan/workspace/biodiversity/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/examples/wordcount.py", line 94, in <module>
    run()
  File "/Users/stefan/workspace/biodiversity/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/examples/wordcount.py", line 89, in run
    output | 'Write' >> WriteToText(known_args.output)
  File "/Users/stefan/workspace/biodiversity/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 585, in __exit__
    self.result = self.run()
  File "/Users/stefan/workspace/biodiversity/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 564, in run
    return self.runner.run_pipeline(self, self._options)
  File "/Users/stefan/workspace/biodiversity/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/portable_runner.py", line 438, in run_pipeline
    job_service_handle = self.create_job_service(options)
  File "/Users/stefan/workspace/biodiversity/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/portable_runner.py", line 317, in create_job_service
    return self.create_job_service_handle(server.start(), options)
  File "/Users/stefan/workspace/biodiversity/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/job_server.py", line 54, in start
    grpc.channel_ready_future(channel).result(timeout=self._timeout)
  File "/Users/stefan/workspace/biodiversity/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_utilities.py", line 140, in result
    self._block(timeout)
  File "/Users/stefan/workspace/biodiversity/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_utilities.py", line 86, in _block
    raise grpc.FutureTimeoutError()
grpc.FutureTimeoutError
```

Any idea what's going on? Thank you for help. I also opened a bug regarding this issue here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-12657

Answer (score 0):

The cluster is started from a docker container. You have to publish the ports so that the Python code executed on the host can access the port.
See https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/docker/ for the `--publish` option used in the `docker run` cmd.

Comment: Actually my issue was caused by the attempt to use `--net=host` on macOS. Apparently, [this doesn't work](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/):

"The host networking driver only works on Linux hosts, and is not supported on Docker Desktop for Mac, Docker Desktop for Windows, or Docker EE for Windows Server."

Therefore, the official instructions are wrong. I would have expected a warning in the documentation and in the CLI.

Comment: @ȘtefanIstrate so is it just about removing that flag on macOS , or is this not possible to do on a mac?